# How to get the next data from sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using sqlite for my fm app.I want to retrieve the next upcoming 3 data from the database using Current time.

My columns are:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proname(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ImageID INTEGER,Title TEXT,FromTiming INTEGER,ToTiming INTEGER);");
```

please help me in writting query for this condition

Comment: Define _next upcoming 3 data_ what do you want, based on what column, what do you have. Please see [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fetch data using:

```
public Cursor fetchMSG(int tId){
        SQLiteDatabase sqdb=getReadableDatabase();
        return  sqdb.rawQuery("select * from proname where "+KEY_FROMTIME+"=" + tId+  " ASC limit 3 ", null);

    }
```

and insert data like:

```
public void insertMSG(String imgId,String title,int fromtime,int totime){
        SQLiteDatabase sqdb=getWritableDatabase();
        sqdb.beginTransaction();
        try{
            ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_IMGID,imgId);
            values.put(KEY_TITLE,title);
            values.put(KEY_FROMTIME,fromtime);
            values.put(KEY_TOTIME,totime);

            sqdb.insert("proname",null,values);

            sqdb.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }catch (Exception ee){ee.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
            sqdb.endTransaction();
            sqdb.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i retrieved the data for the current time but i want to retrieve for upcoming shows using the current show retrieved already..

Comment: is there any query for that

Comment: i dont understand. please tell more

Comment: Why do you insert data here ? He just want a Select for his table

Comment: I just forgot, but focus on what he want.

Comment: Assuming  "2016-11-30 14:00" is a  `fromTiming` of the current show retrieved: `select * from proname
where fromTiming > "2016-11-30 14:00"
order by fromTiming
limit 3`

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 3 * from TABLENAME where COLUMNNAME > GETDATE()
```